# Elasticsearch Aggregation on Aggregation or multiple aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "by_countryCode": {
      "terms": {
            "field":"countryCode.keyword",
            "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "views": {"sum": {"field": "views"}},
        "shares": {"sum": {"field": "shares"}}
      }
  }
  },
  "query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      { "match": { "userId": 1 } },
      { "match": { "artistId": 1001 }},
      { "range": {
        "date" : {
            "gte" : "20170310",
            "lte" : "20170312"
        }
       }
      }
    ]
   }

  }
}
```

This will return the matched items and also give me the aggregation results too. The aggregation is the sum of the views and shares group by the country code.

But I want another sum aggregation. I want the "total sum" and "total shares" too, how could I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the two additional aggregations at the top most level should do it:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "by_countryCode": {
      "terms": {
            "field":"countryCode.keyword",
            "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "views": {"sum": {"field": "views"}},
        "shares": {"sum": {"field": "shares"}}
      }
  },
  "total_views": {
      {"sum": {"field": "views"}}  
  },
  "total_shares": {
      {"sum": {"field": "shares"}}
  },
  "query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      { "match": { "userId": 1 } },
      { "match": { "artistId": 1001 }},
      { "range": {
        "date" : {
            "gte" : "20170310",
            "lte" : "20170312"
        }
       }
      }
    ]
   }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "by_countryCode": {
      "terms": {
            "field":"countryCode.keyword",
            "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "views": {"sum": {"field": "views"}},
        "shares": {"sum": {"field": "shares"}}
      }
  },
  "total_views": {
    "sum": {"field": "views"}
  },
  "total_shares": {
    "sum": {"field": "shares"}
  }

  },
  "query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      { "match": { "userId": 1 } },
      { "match": { "artistId": 1001 }},
      { "range": {
        "date" : {
            "gte" : "20170310",
            "lte" : "20170312"
        }
       }
      }
    ]
   }

  }
}
```

---

Thanks, Roman!

With the help of your codes, I made some small changes. It works!